# Can the keyboard shortcuts define of pgAdmin5 be customized?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using pgAdmin5, I want to customize it's shortcuts, but I can't find out anywhere I can do it.

Would you please tell me?